# MySQL Installation dialog stuck on Windows 7

Tags: installation, mysql

I'm not able to install MySQL on my system. It asks for reconfigure for MySQL server then goes to Types and Networking. It asks to select standalone or other option but doesn't show the next button to progress.

What could be wrong? How do I proceed with the configuration?

[image: Image of installer and the step it's stuck on]

Comment: Hi Seth, I have added the screenshot where I was not able to move forward installing. Next button is also not displaying. I have installed the 64 bit version for server and workbench. but still its not installing. Please help.

Comment: Did you try to change the step on the left?

Comment: Yes tried but nothing is selectable or choosable after this window. If I try the other radio button still nothing happens.

Comment: Is there any steps to be followed for 64 bit installation in Win7 for MySQL server and workbench ?

Comment: If you hit the "Enter" key it will proceed to the next step.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the windows text size to smaller = 100% (seen in https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=85973).

Comment: Hi Julia, I tried this and it worked. Thanks

Comment: But now got stuck at Apply Configuration --> updating start menu link. it is not executing. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

100% works:
1.Play video on youtube (MySql 5.7.20 installation)
2.Use Alt-N for Next, Alt-X for Execute and Alt-F for Finish.